# Python __new__ and __init__ usage

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python module to handle matrices. (I know about numpy, this is just for fun)

So far I have written a few classes, `Matrix`, `Dim`, and `Vec`. `Matrix` and `Vec` are both subclasses of `Dim`. When creating a matrix, one would first start out with a list of lists and they would create a matrix like:

```
startingList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
myMatrix = matrix.Matrix(startingList)
```

This should create a `Matrix`. The created `Matrix` should contain multiple `Dim`s all of the same length. Each of these `Dim`s should contain multiple `Dim`s all of the same length, etc. The last `Dim`, the one that contains numbers, should contain only numbers and should be a `Vec` instead of a `Dim`.

So far this works as I want it to. Here is what I have:

```
from numbers import Number

test2DMat = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
test3DMat = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,0]],[[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]]]

class Dim(list):
    def __new__(cls,inDim):
        # Make sure inDim is iterable
        iter(inDim)

        # If every item in inDim is a number create a Vec
        if all(isinstance(item,Number) for item in inDim):
            #return Vec(inDim)
            return Vec.__new__(cls,inDim)

        # Make sure every item in inDim is iterable
        try:
            for item in inDim: iter(item)
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('All items in a Dim must be iterable')

        # Make sure every item in inDim has the same length
        # or that there are zero items in the list
        if len(set(len(item) for item in inDim)) > 1:
            raise ValueError('All lists in a Dim must be the same length')

        # Actually create the Dim because it passed all the tests
        return list.__new__(cls,inDim)

    def __init__(self,inDim):
        inDim = map(Dim,inDim)
        list.__init__(self,inDim)


class Vec(Dim):
    def __new__(cls,inDim):
        if cls.__name__ not in [Vec.__name__,Dim.__name__]:
            newMat = list.__new__(Vec,inDim)
            newMat.__init__(inDim)
            return newMat
        return list.__new__(Vec,inDim)

    def __init__(self,inDim):
        list.__init__(self,inDim)


class Matrix(Dim):
    def __new__(cls,inMat):
        return Dim.__new__(cls,inMat)

    def __init__(self,inMat):
        super(Matrix,self).__init__(inMat)
```

This works, but as I have little experience overriding `__new__()` I'm fairly certain that this could be better. How can I improve this? Answers need not be specific to use of `__new__` and `__init__`, but that is what I care most about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the thing that was most obvious in your code was that you never used a space after a comma.

Second, you have the Matrix class where you override `__new__` and `__init__`, however it would be work just fine if you'd use `class Matrix(Dim): pass`.

That's where I started to wonder why you define a `Dim` class and than inherit from it for `Matrix` and `Vec`, instead of code `Matrix` and subclass `Vec` from it. Any reason?

I would move the tests from `Dim.__new__`, except for the numbers test, to `__init__`. The iter test is not needed, you'll get an error from the `list` constructor or the for loop anyway.

One issue I see is that `Matrix('abc')` will result in endless recursion, because strings are iterable. Those are the places where I regret the absence of `chr` type in python :)

In `Vec.__new__`, I would let others customize the way they inherit from, why do you check if the class is a `Vec` or a `Dim`?

Last tip, when inheriting types like `list` or `str`, you have to override all the operator overloading methods if you plan on doing things like `Vec((0, 1, 2)) * Vec((2, 3, 4))`

Also:

`[Vec.__name__,Dim.__name__]` use tuples here, memory management

`test2DMat = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` I would break lines here

Comment: I check if the class is a `Vec` or `Dim` (after some modifications I now use `isinstance(cls,Dim)`) because of how `__new__` appears to work. As I stated, I'm not exactly sure how `__new__` works, but it sometimes calls `__init__` but not always. In my tests `__init__` was not getting called for `Vec` and `Dim` so I had to manually call it. Things like this are what I was hoping to get feedback on. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: `Matrix.__init__` and `Matrix.__new__` are empty in this question as I had not yet gotten around to writing them. I also planned to (and have) added things to `Matrix` that are not part of `Dim`. I asked this question before I had written everything I planned to because I mostly cared about the use of `__new__` and `__init__` and wanted to make sure that was as good as it could be before getting too far into the project.

Comment: "If __new__() returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will be invoked like __init__(self[, ...]), where self is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to __new__().

If __new__() does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will not be invoked.", from http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

Comment: Yes, I already had already read that, but my interpretation of it didn't agree with my experience. In code not posted here (a modified version of this) I do not have to call `__init__` if I return a `Vec` and `cls` is `Matrix`. `Matrix` is not an instance of `Vec` so I would have expected to need to manually call `__init__`

Comment: Sounds weird. Could you maybe post the full code?

Comment: upon reviewing my code prior to posting it I found that I was mistaken about my previous comment. I have in fact removed that `if cls.__name__ not in [Vec.__name__,Dim.__name__]:` statement in its entirety. I made some changes per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12958437/1460976 and now that section is unneeded (and could cause `__init__` to be called twice in some cases)